# Accidently removed a users profile

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile

I accidently removed a user profile for 1 user in SharePoint Online.

Under User profiles -> Manage user profiles I selected and removed the user.

How can I restore this user profile?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The user should recreate itself automatically with the next sync from Azure to SharePoint Online directory. When it does:

1) Verify the personal site of the user. Does it look like tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/user_domain_com  or tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/user_domain_com**1**? If there is "1" at the end:

- the user may experience some issues accessing OneDrive from mobile devices
- his files might be missing (they should be under url without 1)

2) Verify how many users appear in People Picker (in web parts or while sharing a site with this user) after you type in his name. If there are 2, you may be able to share with one and not the other. If there is 1, you may receive an error: "Entry for the user is not unique" or "User not found in the directory" while trying to share.

For both situations (or in case the user profile did not get recreated and the user lost access) contact Microsoft support and provide them with the username to fix. Do not use any scripts to attempt to fix the issues yourself (trust me, I know :).

If, however, nothing of this is happening in the nearest (let's say 72h to be on the safe side, but in reality immediately or 24h max), and the user has access to all services, then you need to take no action. Everything got fixed by itself :)